# PHP-MySQL form with 1 field input validation

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP got a simple form with 1 field which has to be validated and its string stripped from both sides.
From the string i keep certain characters and want to match if this stripped string is in mysql DB.
IF it exists in DB then i input the string to DB to another table, if not i discard it.

The problem is that currently everything that i enter is validated by the if statement as true and inserted to the database. It only has to do insert when the if statement is true, not everytime. I got it working without the string stripping but when i strip the string from crap i cant get it working again...

**This is the code with string strip and which validates everything as true**

```
    ...
    $txt=substr($_POST[ZZ_ID],12,-1);

    $test = mysql_query("SELECT ZZcode FROM ZZcodes WHERE ZZcode='$txt'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($test);

    if ($row['ZZcode']== $txt)         
    $sql="INSERT INTO Data
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[ZZ_ID]','$_POST[ID]', TIMESTAMP(8))";
    else
            echo "ZZ code error";
            echo "<br />";
            echo $txt;
     if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
              }
    mysql_close($con)
    ...
```

**Here is the block of code without string strip which works:**

```
    ...
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT ZZcode FROM ZZcodes WHERE ZZcode='$_POST[ZZ_ID]'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($test);

    if ($row['ZZcode']== $_POST[ZZ_ID])
    $sql="INSERT INTO Data
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[ZZ_ID]','$_POST[ID]', TIMESTAMP(8))";
    else
            echo "ZZ koodi ei saa sisestada";
            echo "<br />";
     if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
              }
    mysql_close($con)
    ...
```

Comment: I am aware, when the functionality is fixed i will add protection from sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Just `var_dump($_POST[ZZ_ID])` before you set `$txt=substr($_POST[ZZ_ID],12,-1);`

And then `var_dump($txt)`.

I'm think that `substr()` function is your problem!

Comment: Cant dump the variable as it contains info from which i start stripping. The substr function works fine when i simply echo $txt. Problems occur when i move on to if statement

Comment: Can you post here what value the $_POST[ZZ_ID] gets before the `substr()` ?

Comment: $_POST[ZZ_ID] == 00347508480038613978 and with with stripping $txt== 3861397.

Comment: Even if you put any random value that you're sure that will return false, it will return true ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare strings i suggest you to use a string comparison function such as strcmp. To know more about strcmp visit [strcmp - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

This function will return 0 if the two strings are equal. This comparison is case sensitive.

Comment: cant use strcmp as it has to be validated against a database which contains valid info